# Circle Progress Bar Using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to create circle with multiple different values:

- Starting from 0 to 50 - blue color
- From 50 to 60 - Red color
- From 60 to 100 color yellow like image below

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like below:

Dependency: `jQuery`

```js
function sliceSize(dataNum, dataTotal) {
  return (dataNum / dataTotal) * 360;
}
function addSlice(sliceSize, pieElement, offset, sliceID, color) {
  $(pieElement).append("<div class='slice "+sliceID+"'><span></span></div>");
  var offset = offset - 1;
  var sizeRotation = -179 + sliceSize;
  $("."+sliceID).css({
    "transform": "rotate("+offset+"deg) translate3d(0,0,0)"
  });
  $("."+sliceID+" span").css({
    "transform"       : "rotate("+sizeRotation+"deg) translate3d(0,0,0)",
    "background-color": color
  });
}
function iterateSlices(sliceSize, pieElement, offset, dataCount, sliceCount, color) {
  var sliceID = "s"+dataCount+"-"+sliceCount;
  var maxSize = 179;
  if(sliceSize<=maxSize) {
    addSlice(sliceSize, pieElement, offset, sliceID, color);
  } else {
    addSlice(maxSize, pieElement, offset, sliceID, color);
    iterateSlices(sliceSize-maxSize, pieElement, offset+maxSize, dataCount, sliceCount+1, color);
  }
}
function createPie(dataElement, pieElement) {
  var listData = [];
  $(dataElement+" span").each(function() {
    listData.push(Number($(this).html()));
  });
  var listTotal = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<listData.length; i++) {
    listTotal += listData[i];
  }
  var offset = 0;
  var color = [
    "cornflowerblue", 
    "olivedrab", 
    "orange", 
    "tomato", 
    "crimson", 
    "purple", 
    "turquoise", 
    "forestgreen", 
    "navy", 
    "gray"
  ];
  for(var i=0; i<listData.length; i++) {
    var size = sliceSize(listData[i], listTotal);
    iterateSlices(size, pieElement, offset, i, 0, color[i]);
    $(dataElement+" li:nth-child("+(i+1)+")").css("border-color", color[i]);
    offset += size;
  }
}
createPie(".pieID.legend", ".pieID.pie");
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);

@keyframes bake-pie {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate3d(0,0,0);
  }
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
  background: #EEE;
}
main {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
section {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.pieID {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.pie {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
}
.pie::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #EEE;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
.pie::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  margin: 220px auto;
  
}
.slice {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 200px, 100px);
  animation: bake-pie 1s;
}
.slice span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 200px, 100px);
}
.legend {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #DDD,
              2px 2px 0 #BBB;
}
.legend li {
  width: 110px;
  height: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 0.7em;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  border-left: 1.25em solid black;
}
.legend em {
  font-style: normal;
}
.legend span {
  float: right;
}
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: #DDD;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  
  <section>
    <div class="pieID pie">
      
    </div>
    <ul class="pieID legend">
      <li>
        <em>Cats</em>
        <span>868</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <em>Slugs</em>
        <span>344</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <em>Aliens</em>
        <span>1145</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  
</main>
```

Reference: http://codepen.io/ejsado/pen/cLrlm/

Comment: Bro its working but i Cant able to edit this like "https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GRlk.png" pic. Help to me to get to that pic

Comment: Change colors  like `var color = [
    "cornflowerblue", 
    "seagreen", 
    "gray", 
    "tomato", 
    "crimson", 
    "purple", 
    "turquoise", 
    "forestgreen", 
    "navy", 
    "gray"
  ];`

Comment: No bro,I am not talking about color, I want to take off that cats,Slugs and Aliens and Insert words in the Middle of the Circle

Comment: Add this css `.pieID::before {
  content: "EQUITY 67%";
  font-weight:700;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 90px;
}`

Comment: Bro how to take out cats,Slugs and Aliens

Comment: add `display:none;` in `.legend`css  class

Comment: Thank you bro. It works so well. Thank you Very much for the immediate response

Comment: Accept this as accepted answer if it worked for you. @perinban

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136636/discussion-between-perinban-and-ambrish-pathak).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS only solution:

```css
    body { background: #545b7a;}
    
    div {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      margin: auto;
      position: absolute;
      background: #fa0 -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fa0 50%, #0af 50%);
      background: #fa0 linear-gradient(to right, #fa0 50%, #0af 50%);
      color: #0af;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
                transform: rotate(180deg);
      }
    }
    @keyframes spin {
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
                transform: rotate(180deg);
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes background {
      50% {
        background-color: currentColor;
      }
    }
    @keyframes background {
      50% {
        background-color: currentColor;
      }
    }
    div::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 80%;
      height: 80%;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      margin: auto;
      background: #545b7a;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    div::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      background-color: inherit;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0 / 50%;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
              transform: rotate(0);
      -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
              transform-origin: 0 50%;
      -webkit-animation: 50s spin infinite linear, 100s background infinite step-end;
              animation: 50s spin infinite linear, 100s background infinite step-end;
      -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
              animation-play-state: paused;
      -webkit-animation-delay: inherit;
              animation-delay: inherit;
    }
```

```html
<div style="animation-delay: -35s"></div>
```

Comment: I just formatted it as a code snippet, hit run and you can see it working ;)